# PHP built-in server redirect logs

Tags: php, unix, php-builtin-server

I need to redirect my php built in server log file into a file.

i try :

```
php -S adress:port -t . > logs.txt
```

the problem is it's just putting inside the launch text.

and `logs.txt 2>&1`

but it's make my page php look like my error

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 Development Server started at Sat Feb 13 09:40:05 2016 Listening on XXXXXX ....
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score -1):

you could filer it out using grep.

```
php -S adress:port -t . | grep -v "Development Server started at" > logs.txt
```

And remember: The server is not supposed for productive use and log handling is just one of the limitations.